# When 'ViewState' of a form is changed?

Tags: c#, viewstate, eventvalidation

There are to hidden fields on every standard `ASP.NET` form: `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION`. When the value for these fields would change for a specific form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They change whenever any property/attribute of any page's control whose `ViewState` is set to `True` gets modified. (`EventValidation` would change whenever any control's 'value' changes)